# Trying to set up a Mute button on Android app (java)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to setup a simple mute button on the GUI of my app.  Which when selected: 
1. mutes the Media Volume
an when selected again,
2. unmutes the Media Volume

I am new to Java.  I don't know what bundle to import or which statement is best for this.
Here's what I have so far:

```
//Mute Button
    btnMute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wmute);
```

Button XML:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/wmute"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mute" />
```

Comment: does your app have an object of the `AudioManager` class?

Comment: What have you tried in regards to the actual muting of the Audio? This code above *should* work in brining your layout button into your java code for manipulation.

Comment: Yes I have imported Audio Manager

Comment: @mustafa see below, then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

selected: 1

```
@Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

      switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.wmute:
        AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        AudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
         break;
      default:
         break;
      }

   }
```

selected: 2

```
AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL );
AudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
```

Comment: should I put the above code below 
btnMute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wmute);
?

Comment: You must first implement a listener after that you can put the code inside

Comment: [Button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Button.html) and [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html)

Comment: Hi, I have tried to enter above code, but I'm getting following errors:
1.Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody
after doing so, i get the following error
2.Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setStreamSolo(int, boolean) from the type AudioManager

Comment: This is what I have so far:
//Mute Button
        btnMute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wmute);
        btnMute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         
          public void onClick(View v) {
             switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.wmute:
              AudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                    AudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
                    break;
                    default:
                     break;
             }}

Comment: try to send me your complet code so that i can arrange it for you. festus@tamakloe.de

Comment: Hi Festus, did you get my e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

Read through [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html).  Basically you can manipulate your sound with the `adjustVolume()` and `adjustStreamVolume()` methods.

Use your button to fire an event that calls either one of these methods to manipulate the volume of whatever stream you want to manipulate.

You can use these methods to adjust volume on notifications, music, Ringtones, etc...

Comment: Thanks Marco, that's really helpful.  I'll read through and try to get an understanding of it and then I'm sure I'll have the answer.

Comment: @Mustafa no problem, I referenced some relevant Java documentation in Festus' answer as well.  don't forget to upvote and accept if either one of our answers helps you.